# Parse dynamic JSON into java object using retrofit + Gson?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have to parse dynamic **JSON** to my model class.
Here, the date is the dynamic object and corresponding value may be three types.

1.date : `value = absent`

2.date : `value = holyday`

if present then
3.date : object

**JSON** model:

```
{
  "attendance":{
      "2017-02-20": "Absence",
      "2017-02-21": "holiday:Shaheed Day and International Mother Language Day",
      "2019-07-10": {
      "attendance_type": "fixed",
      "office_entry_time": "07:02:05",
      "office_out_time": "15:35:07",
      "worked_have_todo": "14:00:00",
      "worked_has_done": "08:33:02",
      "late_in_time": null,
      "early_leave_time": null,
      "working_diffrent": "00:33:02",
      "working_diffrent_sign": "+",
      "location": {
        "in": "B",
        "out": "B"
      }
    }
  },
  "total": {
    "total_worked_have_todo": "64:0:0",
    "total_worked_has_done": "73:28:3",
    "total_worked_day": 8,
    "avarage_worked_has_done_per_day": "9:11:0"
  }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This JSON should be fixed first, because it's structure is just wrong. You should at least. Have an array of dates where key is date and value is "Absence" or "holiday".

Comment: The JSON is not structured correctly, you should tell the person who created the webservice to structure it better, with predefined keys.
You cannot expect one key to be a string or an object in two different cases.

Comment: Thanks for reply @meh ... but the developer made the api in php javaScript and run as web service...  i think how they display that API in website...? I create two different class + models + ui for this api...! one for absent/holyday and another for present object.... ! am i right ?...

Comment: Thanks @Watercayman for edit my mistake.